# cat multiple file in script truncates data when scheduled in cron

Tags: linux, files, cron, cat

I'm cat'ing multiple files in a bash script on OEL 6.

```
for f in /share/scripts/stats/*.stat; do (cat "${f}"; echo) >>   /share/scripts/stats/finalmail.html; done
```

When the script is triggered manually it appends all files perfectly. But when the script runs from cron (every 5 mins) sometimes (~10% of the time) only part of the data from 1-2 files are appended. I tried listing file size of each before this cat operation is called. The final file size sometimes is not the sum of all the file sizes.

Comment: `cat` stands for concatenate..you should be able to pass `*.stat` to it. If the only reason you have a loop is to print a separator between files, use `tail -n +1 *.stat` instead

Answer (score 1):

In all likelihood, your script sometimes triggers at the same time that the file is being written. When `cat` runs, it copies the data that is currently there. It has no way to know that more data will be added later.

To avoid this, assuming that the files are meant to be produced quickly, the best way is to change the program that is producing the data. Instead of directly writing to the final name, write to a temporary file and rename the temporary file when all the data is present, e.g.

```
gather_data --origin=somewhere >somewhere.stat.tmp &&
mv somewhere.stat.tmp somewhere.stat
```

If you can't change the producing process, then you can react to the files being closed using [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify). Depending on how those files are created and removed, it might make more sense to use [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en), e.g. you can use this incrontab line:

```
/share/scripts/stats IN_CLOSE_WRITE case $@/$# in *.stat) new_stat_file $@/$# esac
```

`new_stat_file` would be a script that incorporates the new file. Don't just run something like `cat *.stat` there, because it could also pick up partial files. Rename the files, or a copy of the files, e.g.

```
/share/scripts/stats IN_CLOSE_WRITE case $@/$# in *.stat) ln $@/$# /share/scripts/stats/ready/; esac
```

and then pick up the files from `/share/scripts/stats/ready` instead of `/share/scripts/stats`.

Comment: The stat files are created by a first script(which is also in cron). This second script which combines all the stat files run after 5 mins. The stat files are pretty small (~2KB-5KB) and takes few seconds(5-30Sec max) to generate.

Even though the stat files are created long back before this script triggers, the cat operation somehow tries to does not work from cron.

I have verified the stat files before this script concatenates them. They are complete and are created minimum 2-3 mins before this script is triggered. The stat files are created by redirection operators from 1st script.